# What is this tree

Tags: identification

[image][image]
In southern WV.  White blooms on a long stem.

Comment: Looks similar to a horse chestnut. Do the blooms look like white lilac?

Comment: No, they're not that big.  Closer to lily of the valley size.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: This is not horse chestnut, I think this tree is native to North America because I have never seen something alike here in Europe.

Comment: Could be a chokecherry tree, then.

Answer (score 1):

Nysso sylvatica, sour gum, black tupelo ; The flowers are very small , I have never noticed them. Leaves are very red in the fall.  Looks just like the one in my yard ( although the lowest leaves are ten feet high).

Comment: Just heard back from Va Tech(Vtree app).  He says it's blackgum!

Comment: Same thing . I have heard" sour gum" most often.